# Auth_failure when connecting to wireless network in Ubuntu 14

Tags: 12.04, wireless, drivers, wpa-supplicant

I installed Ubuntu and I've been working on this for a while now and I really need some help bad. I setup a Realtek RTL8192E windows xp driver on ubuntu using ndiswrapper and configured wpa_supplicant.

I followed these tutorials

Configure the rtl8190 with ndiswrapper:
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1433401

Configure wpa_supplicant:
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=263136

I also ran a wireless script for troubleshooting (toward the end)

Here's my wpa_supplicant.conf file:

```
ctrl_interface=/var/run/wpa_supplicant
#ap_scan=2

network={
    ssid="2WIRE201"
    scan_ssid=1
    proto=WPA RSN
    key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
    pairwise=CCMP TKIP
    group=CCMP TKIP
    psk=2efdade6c94ad65fda3e453879cf0a81a8cd09ec3fe1886154c0ba0c35478d13
}
```

My router is configured to accept wpa-tkip and wpa2-aes so why am I getting this message when I type this:

```
sudo wpa_supplicant -Dwext -iwlan0 -c/etc/wpa_supplicant.conf
```

And I get this:

```
Successfully initialized wpa_supplicant
ioctl[SIOCSIWENCODEEXT]: Invalid argument
ioctl[SIOCSIWENCODEEXT]: Invalid argument
wlan0: Trying to associate with 60:c3:97:b4:73:f9 (SSID='2WIRE201' freq=2452 MHz)
wlan0: Associated with 60:c3:97:b4:73:f9
wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-DISCONNECTED bssid=60:c3:97:b4:73:f9 reason=0
wlan0: Trying to associate with 60:c3:97:b4:73:f9 (SSID='2WIRE201' freq=2452 MHz)
wlan0: Associated with 60:c3:97:b4:73:f9
wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-DISCONNECTED bssid=60:c3:97:b4:73:f9 reason=0
wlan0: Trying to associate with 60:c3:97:b4:73:f9 (SSID='2WIRE201' freq=2452 MHz)
wlan0: Associated with 60:c3:97:b4:73:f9
wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-DISCONNECTED bssid=60:c3:97:b4:73:f9 reason=0
wlan0: Trying to associate with 60:c3:97:b4:73:f9 (SSID='2WIRE201' freq=2452 MHz)
wlan0: Associated with 60:c3:97:b4:73:f9
wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-DISCONNECTED bssid=60:c3:97:b4:73:f9 reason=0
wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-SSID-TEMP-DISABLED id=0 ssid="2WIRE201" auth_failures=1 duration=10
```

Results of wireless troubleshooting Script

```
########## wireless info START ##########

##### release #####

Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04 LTS
Release:    14.04
Codename:   trusty

##### kernel #####

Linux anthony-vm 3.13.0-24-generic #46-Ubuntu SMP Thu Apr 10 19:11:08 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

##### lspci #####

00:19.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Intel Corporation 82578DC Gigabit Network Connection [8086:10f0] (rev 05)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device [8086:0000]
    Kernel driver in use: e1000e

03:01.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8190 802.11n PCI Wireless Network Adapter [10ec:8190]
    Subsystem: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8190 802.11n PCI Wireless Network Adapter [10ec:8190]
    Kernel driver in use: ndiswrapper
03:03.0 FireWire (IEEE 1394) [0c00]: Texas Instruments TSB43AB22A IEEE-1394a-2000 Controller (PHY/Link) [iOHCI-Lynx] [104c:8023]

##### lsusb #####

Bus 002 Device 004: ID 046d:0819 Logitech, Inc. Webcam C210
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 058f:6362 Alcor Micro Corp. Flash Card Reader/Writer
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 009 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 008 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 007 Device 002: ID 046d:c068 Logitech, Inc. G500 Laser Mouse
Bus 007 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 005 Device 002: ID 10f5:0230 Turtle Beach 
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 004 Device 002: ID 046d:c22d Logitech, Inc. G510 Gaming Keyboard
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub

##### PCMCIA Card Info #####

##### rfkill #####

##### iw reg get #####

country 00:
    (2402 - 2472 @ 40), (3, 20)
    (2457 - 2482 @ 40), (3, 20), PASSIVE-SCAN, NO-IBSS
    (2474 - 2494 @ 20), (3, 20), NO-OFDM, PASSIVE-SCAN, NO-IBSS
    (5170 - 5250 @ 40), (3, 20), PASSIVE-SCAN, NO-IBSS
    (5735 - 5835 @ 40), (3, 20), PASSIVE-SCAN, NO-IBSS

##### interfaces #####

auto lo
iface lo inet dhcp
pre-up wpa_supplicant -Bw -Dwext -wlan0 -c/etc/wpa_supplicant.conf
post-down killall -q wpa_supplicant

##### iwconfig #####

wlan0     IEEE 802.11g  ESSID:off/any  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.412 GHz  Access Point: Not-Associated   
          Bit Rate:65 Mb/s   Tx-Power:20 dBm   Sensitivity=0/3  
          RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off
          Link Quality:0  Signal level:0  Noise level:0
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:0   Missed beacon:0

##### route #####

Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface

##### resolv.conf #####

##### nm-tool #####

NetworkManager Tool

State: disconnected

- Device: wlan0 ----------------------------------------------------------------
  Type:              802.11 WiFi
  Driver:            ndiswrapper
  State:             disconnected
  Default:           no
  HW Address:        <MAC address removed>

  Capabilities:

  Wireless Properties
    WEP Encryption:  yes
    WPA Encryption:  yes
    WPA2 Encryption: yes

  Wireless Access Points 
    2WIRE201:        Infra, <MAC address removed>, Freq 2452 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 75 WPA WPA2
    LisaJae:         Infra, <MAC address removed>, Freq 2437 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 52 WPA2
    ATT346:          Infra, <MAC address removed>, Freq 2437 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 50 WPA WPA2
    HOME-1842:       Infra, <MAC address removed>, Freq 2462 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 52 WPA WPA2

- Device: eth0 -----------------------------------------------------------------
  Type:              Wired
  Driver:            e1000e
  State:             unavailable
  Default:           no
  HW Address:        <MAC address removed>

  Capabilities:
    Carrier Detect:  yes

  Wired Properties
    Carrier:         off

##### NetworkManager.state #####

[main]
NetworkingEnabled=true
WirelessEnabled=true
WWANEnabled=true
WimaxEnabled=true

##### NetworkManager.conf #####

[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile,ofono
dns=dnsmasq

[ifupdown]
managed=false

##### iwlist #####

No way to aquire root rights found.

##### iwlist channel #####

wlan0     14 channels in total; available frequencies :
          Channel 01 : 2.412 GHz
          Channel 02 : 2.417 GHz
          Channel 03 : 2.422 GHz
          Channel 04 : 2.427 GHz
          Channel 05 : 2.432 GHz
          Channel 06 : 2.437 GHz
          Channel 07 : 2.442 GHz
          Channel 08 : 2.447 GHz
          Channel 09 : 2.452 GHz
          Channel 10 : 2.457 GHz
          Channel 11 : 2.462 GHz
          Channel 12 : 2.467 GHz
          Channel 13 : 2.472 GHz
          Channel 14 : 2.484 GHz
          Current Frequency:2.412 GHz (Channel 1)

##### lsmod #####

ndiswrapper           283985  0 

##### modinfo #####

filename:       /lib/modules/3.13.0-24-generic/updates/dkms/ndiswrapper.ko
license:        GPL
version:        1.59
description:    NDIS wrapper driver
author:         ndiswrapper team <ndiswrapper-general@lists.sourceforge.net>
srcversion:     DC1EFD919FDF2DB80D424C6
depends:        
vermagic:       3.13.0-24-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
parm:           if_name:Network interface name or template (default: wlan%d) (charp)
parm:           proc_uid:The uid of the files created in /proc (default: 0). (int)
parm:           proc_gid:The gid of the files created in /proc (default: 0). (int)
parm:           debug:debug level (int)
parm:           hangcheck_interval:The interval, in seconds, for checking if driver is hung. (default: 0) (int)
parm:           utils_version:Compatible version of utils (read only: 1.9) (charp)

##### modules #####

lp
rtc
ndiswrapper

##### blacklist #####

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-ath_pci.conf]
blacklist ath_pci

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf]
blacklist evbug
blacklist usbmouse
blacklist usbkbd
blacklist eepro100
blacklist de4x5
blacklist eth1394
blacklist snd_intel8x0m
blacklist snd_aw2
blacklist i2c_i801
blacklist prism54
blacklist bcm43xx
blacklist garmin_gps
blacklist asus_acpi
blacklist snd_pcsp
blacklist pcspkr
blacklist amd76x_edac

[/etc/modprobe.d/fbdev-blacklist.conf]
blacklist arkfb
blacklist aty128fb
blacklist atyfb
blacklist radeonfb
blacklist cirrusfb
blacklist cyber2000fb
blacklist gx1fb
blacklist gxfb
blacklist kyrofb
blacklist matroxfb_base
blacklist mb862xxfb
blacklist neofb
blacklist nvidiafb
blacklist pm2fb
blacklist pm3fb
blacklist s3fb
blacklist savagefb
blacklist sisfb
blacklist tdfxfb
blacklist tridentfb
blacklist viafb
blacklist vt8623fb

##### udev rules #####

# PCI device 0x8086:0x10f0 (e1000e)
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="<MAC address removed>", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="eth*", NAME="eth0"

# PCI device 0x10ec:0x8190 (ndiswrapper)
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="<MAC address removed>", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="wlan*", NAME="wlan0"

##### dmesg #####

[   11.023828] ndiswrapper: module verification failed: signature and/or  required key missing - tainting kernel
[   11.024621] ndiswrapper version 1.59 loaded (smp=yes, preempt=no)
[   12.524790] ndiswrapper: driver net819xp (Realtek Semiconductor Corp.,07/01/2009,1677.1.0708.2009) loaded
[   12.599971] ndiswrapper: using IRQ 22
[   13.246570] wlan0: ethernet device <MAC address removed> using NDIS driver: net819xp, version: 0x500a5, NDIS version: 0x500, vendor: 'Realtek RTL8190 Wireless LAN (Mini-)PCI NIC                                     ', 10EC:8190.5.conf
[   13.246597] wlan0: encryption modes supported: WEP; TKIP with WPA, WPA2, WPA2-PSK; AES/CCMP with WPA, WPA2, WPA2-PSK
[   15.550988] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready
[   15.551131] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready

########## wireless info END ############
```

So whats the issue here and how do I fix this? Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I just ended up deleting `wpa_supplicant.conf` file meaning to just start anew, but the minute I deleted the file everything worked. Connection is intermittent sometimes, but that may just be my wireless card.

Answer (score 0):

-Dwext is wrong for your driver. Check the correct driver by typing wpa_supplicant - - help
In my case, it was nl180211

Comment: Please try to use the "backtick" character (\`) to enclose terminal commands/parameters. For example: `-Dwext` is wrong for your driver. Check the correct driver by typing `wpa_supplicant --help`...